# How to get stack trace of exception happening in __del__?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

Is there an easy way to get stack trace printed for an exception that happens in `__del__`? In my case, there's no `__del__` method defined for this object

```
Exception TypeError: "'NoneType' object is not callable" in <bound method InteractiveSession.__del__ of <tensorflow.python.client.session.InteractiveSession object at 0x2867710>> ignored
```

Comment: The `__del__` method should be avaliable in the superclass I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to detect the error manually inside `__del__`:

```
def __del__(self):
    try:
        cleanup()
    except Exception:
        import traceback
        traceback.print_exc()

        # Let the error keep propagating.
        raise
```

There's no way to configure what Python does with exceptions raised by `__del__`. It's a [direct call](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/typeobject.c#l5823) to [`PyErr_WriteUnraisable`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/errors.c#l660), with no place to provide a callback, no configuration possible to print the stack trace, and nowhere to retrieve the exception information afterward.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) it says this:

> Due to the precarious circumstances under which `__del__()` methods are invoked, exceptions that occur during their execution are ignored, and a warning is printed to `sys.stderr` instead.

So the answer is no, you cannot get the stack trace from an exception from  `__del__` unless you modify it yourself.